# Loopback query which compares field values

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Say i have the following Scheme

```
Product: {
  Quantity: Number,
  SelledQuantity: Number
}
```

Would it be possible to write a query where all the results returned are where `Quantity=SelledQuantity`?

If so, is there a way to use it when doing a populate? (Perhaps inside the match field in the opts object ?)

I use mysql connector.

Comment: Which connector are you using?

Comment: i use mysql connector

Answer (score 0):

yes as I understood your problem you can do this by following rest call.
http://localhost:3000/api/products?filter[where][SelledQuantity]=n

this will give you the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more related to MySQL query. But you can achieve it by javascript as follows:

```
Product.find({}, fuction(err, products) {
    if(err) throw err;

    //considering products as array of product. Otherwise you can get to depth for array of product.
    var filteredProducts = products.filter(function(p1) {
        return p1.Quantity === p1.SelledQuantity;
    });

   //Your desired output
   console.log(filteredProducts);
});
```

This will be slow but will work for smaller database size. For more optimized answer, ask the question in mysql section with respect to database and table structure.